# Is it possible to use media queries with tags such as <div id='first_area'>?

Tags: css, jsp, media-queries

Trying to develop a webpage with jsps and some css. 
Encountered a problem with media queries.

```
    @media screen and (min-width:500px) { 
        #first_area {
             display: none; 
        }
    }
```

This is the code that I typed on css file that is linked with my index.jsp. 
But the section that is wrapped with div tag named id='first_area' 
does not change (first area does not disappear) even when screen is smaller than 500px.

I am wondering if this is a problem with my code/ or media queries are only supposed to use with tags that already exists? (ex. div, span)
What I am trying to do is making the index.jsp page responsive. 
Please help.

Comment: Have you got a meta tag in head section? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: yes, I do have a meta tag. .. Exact same one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the div if the screen is smaller than 500px you should use `max-width` instead of `min-width`.

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px) { 
   #first_area {
    display: none; 
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried both but media query does not work either way.

Comment: Can you please regenerate your issue on fiddle?. That might help me to understand what is the exact issue you are facing. @ZIO